# Docker configuration - Spring Cloud DataFlow server

Tags: docker-registry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to spring cloud data flow, and I am trying register the app in the spring-cloud-dataflow-local server using dataflow-shell. 
With following command on dataflowshell.

*dataflow:>app register --type task --name my-service --uri docker:my.jfrog.io/myrepo/my-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT*

But dataflow server could not pull image from remote docker registry due to authentication failure exception. I have pasted the Error message below.

*Unable to find image 'my.jfrog.io/myrepo/my-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://'my.jfrog.io/v2/myrepo/my-service/manifests/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: unknown: **Authentication is required**.
See 'docker run --help'.*

Looking for any help on Docker configuration for spring-cloud-dataflow-local server, could find documentation on Maven configuration but not on docker.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SCDF's local-server supports Docker based artifact resolution; however, the resolution of artifacts from the private registry is not supported yet. Since the local-server is used for development, the use of public Docker registry or Maven are the recommended options.

I've created [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local#74](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/issues/74) for tracking - please feel free to submit your use-case and/or contribute to the project - we would love to review and collaborate with you on the pull-request.

Comment: I have taken a look at this, and as I've written [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/issues/74) I think there is not much we can/need to do. Can you pull your image using plain `docker` after doing a `docker login`?

Comment: @gvk: Please refer to Eric's explanation in the GH issue. Let us know what you find out.

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry for delay in response, Yes I am able to pull image using plain docker but SCDF cannot pull the image